# How to remove extra digits from user input in currency and how to check if the user entered nothing in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, currency, str-replace

Please help me, I've been stuck in these issue for a few days. 
I have a web form that will take payments in asp.net and language is C#.

The textbox is to accept currency amount from user. My requirement is that if the user enters for example 75, on _TextChanged event it will switch to 75.00. I got this part to work. But my code does not check for the three character after the position of . and remove the extra zeros. 
My questions:
1. How can I remove the extra zeros if the input is longer than two digits after the decimal point?
2. What can I do if the user does not enter any number in the textbox?
I've tried and I just get errors or it messes up the whole code.

```
protected void txtAmount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        string textBoxData = txtAmount.Text;

        int textLength = textBoxData.Length;

        int position = txtAmountToPay.Text.IndexOf("."); //Position is the decimal

        if (position == -1)
        {
            textBoxData = textBoxData + ".50"; // when you enter 75 you get 75.50
        }
        if (position == textLength -2 )
        {
            textBoxData = textBoxData + "4"; // when you enter 75.0 you get 75.04
        }
        if (position == textLength -1)
        {
            textBoxData = textBoxData + "30"; // when you enter 75. you get 75.30
        }
        if (position >= textLength - 3) // This part does not work
        {
            textBoxData == textBoxData.Replace(-3);// if user enters 75.0000 it will remove all the other digits after the two 0s after the decimal point
        }


    txtAmount.Text = textBoxData.ToString();
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answer is for server-side validation. I think it's more optimize if you use client-side validation for this. It will validate the input even without postback. Try to look at this sample:

```
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RVF1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
   ErrorMessage="Required" Display="Dynamic" />
<asp:CompareValidator id="CheckFormat1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Operator="DataTypeCheck"
   Type="Currency"  Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Illegal format for currency" />
<asp:RangeValidator id="RangeCheck1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
   Type="Currency" Minimum="1" Maximum="999.99" ErrorMessage="Out of range" Display="Dynamic" />
```

This will validate your text inputs.

- 1st: `asp:RequiredFieldValidator` checks the input if null or empty;
- 2nd: `asp:CompareValidator` checks the input if they are in Currency
  format;
- and 3rd: `asp:RangeValidator` is to validate the range of your values. (good for value
  ceiling and flooring)

[Here's a simple DEMO.](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showaspx.asp?filename=demo_reqfieldvalidator)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use regular expressions and look for a pattern of XX.XX , if the input is wrong, then the user must fix the input.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pattern = @"^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$";
    if(Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, pattern))
        MessageBox.Show("Correct Input.");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong Input!");
}
```

[Regular Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)

Comment: Iker, I did that at first but my boss wants me to fix the user's input and cater to the user. I got the first part to work but I need help if the user enters 45.000, it will take out the last 0 and what about the empty textbox?

Comment: Well, Is my PERSONAL opinion that your boss is wrong. You must sanitize user input first. Why go into so much trouble of fixing every messed up scenario when you can kill it all from the root.

Comment: @user2644103, You can cater the user's input just before they submit the form with my answer..=D